# Looping in Vb.Net

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, for-loop

I have a vb.net code from a datagrid to insert importer's record into Ms SQL Database. The code is not working satisfactorily. For multiple importers, it inserts repeated rows of data and does not insert any records for single importers. Can someone help me out?

```
Private Sub UpdateImporterBalance()
    Dim intReturnValue As Integer = 0
    Dim SqlCmd As String = "Insert into Importer_Import (Order_ID, Importer, Quantity, Product, Storage_Charge) values (@Order_ID, @Importer, @Quantity, @Product, @Storage_Charge)"

    Dim ConnObj As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(clsGlobals.ConnString)
    Dim CmdObj As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SqlCmd, ConnObj)

    ConnObj.Open()

    CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Order_ID", SqlDbType.Int)
    CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Product", SqlDbType.Int)
    CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Importer", SqlDbType.Int)
    CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Int)
    CmdObj.Parameters.Add("@Storage_Charge", SqlDbType.Decimal)

    For i = 0 To Me.dgvImporter.RowCount - 2
        CmdObj.Parameters("@Order_ID").Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderID.Text)
        CmdObj.Parameters("@Product").Value = Convert.ToInt32(cboProductName.SelectedValue)
        CmdObj.Parameters("@Importer").Value = Convert.ToInt32(Me.dgvImporter.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value)
        CmdObj.Parameters("@Quantity").Value = CInt(Me.dgvImporter.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value)
        CmdObj.Parameters("@Storage_Charge").Value = CDbl(Me.dgvImporter.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        intReturnValue = CInt(CmdObj.ExecuteNonQuery())
    Next
    ConnObj.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question?  Can't help you without knowing what you want to do...

Comment: I am trying to insert importer's record from a datagrid. For single importer, the code does not insert any record but inserts multiple repeated records for multiple importers.

Comment: Why are you looping from 0 to x - 2?  You will always be missing one row from your insert, which is why if you only have one record, it doesn't get added.  Unless there's something special about your grid, you should be using -1 instead.

Comment: maybe to miss the new row at the bottom which is empty

Comment: I would use a `Try/Catch` to find what it says the error is - maybe the insert statement - check the values

Comment: The `Order_Id` may not be incrementing at the same position as the DB?

Comment: The Suggestion helped but it still inserting duplicate records.

Comment: Place ExecuteNonQuery outside loop.